# Why does my queue event delay not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue

I need your help.

I'm working with Laravel 5.5 queue and with Linux supervisor tool (Exactly like it the documentation)

Now I have a very weird issue.

When I use this command without delay

```
event(new NewOrderHasBeenPlaceEvent($get_order_details, $tran_id, $customerDet->phone));
```

It's working fine.

But when I use the delay option

```
 event(new NewOrderHasBeenPlaceEvent($get_order_details, $tran_id, $customerDet->phone))->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5));
```

I got an error:
**Call to a member function delay() on array** but queue has been executed as expected.

I tried to google but nothing can be found, this got me stuck for whole day. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not suppose to use delay() on event() helper. You can queue the event listeners by implementing ShouldQueue which queues the listener code but not while firing the event.

If you want to use delay, you can make a job class and dispatch that with delay options i.e. MyJob::dispatch()->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5))

Comment: I' was confused between event and job as it really similar in my opinion, now after switch to job asper your suggestion I can use delay. Thanks